# springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate prepared statement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm new to using Spring's JdbcTemplate. I was able to successfully receive results, but now I am trying to do a prepared statement, but how do I pass it `stateName`?

```
public State getStateByName(String stateName) {
    State state = template.query("select id from state where LOWER(state_name) = LOWER(?) order by id LIMIT 1",
            (result) -> {
                State stateTmp = new State();
                stateTmp.setId(result.getLong("id"));
                return stateTmp;
            });
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different overloads of query allow you to pass parameters.

For example:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-